# Relative paths in scripts executed by cron jobs

Tags: python, cron

I'm setting up my first cron job and it's not working.  I think the problem may be a relative path issue.

Given cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * python2.7 /home/path/to/my/script/my_script.py
```

and my_script.py:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
cur = db.cursor()
...
```

How do I make sure that `my_script.py` looks for `my_db.db` in `/home/path/to/my/script/` (the same directory that houses `my_script.py`) and not whatever directory crontab lives?

Other suggestions for troubleshooting are also welcome.

Note - I think the issue may be a path issue because when I try running `my_script.py` using `python2.7 /home/path/to/my/script/my_script.py` from any location other than `/home/path/to/my/script/`, I get an "unable to open database" error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(dir_path, 'my_db.db'))
cur = db.cursor()
...
```

Remember that Python's [os.path module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) is your best friend when manipulating paths.

Comment: Thanks!  This approach enables me to run my script using `python2.7 /home/path/to/my/script/my_script.py`...which is great.  The cron job still doesn't work, though, so I need to continue troubleshooting.  I guess the good news is that I've eliminated one theory and learned about os.path.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to do it a bit differently:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
db = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
```

using  chdir will allow to execute you script in local directory and allow you to keep all local references unchanged if you have more than one it may save you some time :)

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck for a while because I wasn't using the full path for the python command, (which can be checked with `which python` ).

You might also try to set the PATH in a crontab file.